# Changing the temp from 200/60 in any degree triggers thermal runaway

Tags: temperature, thermal-runaway

I am new to 3D printing and having a strange issue I don't understand and would love some help with. I have an Ender 3 Pro and when I use the settings 200 °C & 60 °C it prints fine. However, I want to change the bed to 55 °C as the bottom layers are melting a bit. I changed this in Cura to 200 °C & 55 °C and get a thermal runaway after 20 minutes or so. I hit resume and the same thing after about 20 minutes, however, the times vary.

I did a PID using the same set temps 200 °C & 55 °C and still thermal runaway. So I changed all the numbers back to 200 °C & 60 °C and ran a PID on this original temps and ran perfect (except for the first layers melting a bit)

The odd part is the bed temp holds fine when adjusted to 55 °C, it's the hot end that starts to drop a few degrees (5 degrees) which triggers the runaway. Is this a fan issue (currently at 100%)? Before I started changing things I wanted to ask here.

Looking forward to your feedback. BTW I am able to change the PID right on the machine and have no experience altering G-code or the knowledge but am willing to try?

Comment: I assume you're getting a thermal runaway error.  Is there any evidence of the printer actually starting into thermal runaway?

Comment: Also what is the model of your 3D printer?  Your temperatures sound like you're printing PLA.

Comment: yes running hatchbox pla black. ender 3 pro  is all i know. Yes its a thermal runaway. I have been watching it and seeing the hot end temp drop.

Comment: i thought a thermal runaway was when things get way too hot?

Comment: The bottom layers experience elephant's foot, not melting. PLA only melts at ~180 °C

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a thermostat problem, 60 degrees shouldn't be melting the first layers with PLA.

I would try manually checking the temperatures and move forwards from whatever results I got from that.

If the heats were fine, then I'd be inclined to return it as a faulty unit if it's under warranty.

Comment: I have changed the thermistor multiple times and definetly not. Im thinking its a G-code issue.

Comment: How could it be gcode? The gcode just sets the temperature right at the start if you're not doing fancy modifications to it. Have you tried flashing the firmware? I was going to suggest that but unsure what it would do to the warranty status

Comment: I bought this unopened from a third party. I have not flashed the firmware. I will look into that. I have printed 4 10+ hour prints all beautifully since I started this thread. All at 200/60. so strange that changing the temp down 5 degrees on bed drops the hotend. What do you think about it being a fan issue? Maybe all both bed and hotend fans are firing at the same time?

Comment: I don't know sorry, but the firmware controls the fans. I have never had a fan issue so have no experience with that. The fact that the issue is intermittent could be a capacitor issue, but thats a board problem. If your board is playing up then you need professional help unless you're an electrician

Comment: I still think there is something wrong with your heat readings, I have done 2, 3 and 4 day prints that don't have any melting bottom layers at 60 degrees bed

Comment: Theres really no melting at all. I think im being a perfectionist.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that at all... good luck printing

Answer (score 0):

Could be a bad thermistor, could just need a pid tune. I would start with pid tuning it, if that doesn’t work I would swap it for a new one. Don’t forget to pid tune the new one if you end up going that route.

Comment: The OP states that they have *already* changed the thermistor (multiple times) in [this comment](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/19368/changing-the-temp-from-200-60-in-any-degree-triggers-thermal-runaway/21404#comment37044_19370)